# ng-repeat Values with ng-rateit

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need repeat keys name from an object and values from another json object.

avis.name works but the score(model.score) doesn't want showing up. help
for info, im using **angular-rateit** directive

code look like:

```js
            $scope.model = [
                {
                    "score": 5
                },
                {
                    "score": 3
                },
                {
                    "score": 2
                }
            ]
            
            $scope.allavispossible = [
            {
            "name": "presentation"
            },
            {
            "name": "efficacite"
            },
            "name": "puissance"
            ]
```

```html
<div ng-repeat="avis in allavispossible">
<span class="namecaracforvoteaddproduct">{{avis.name}}</span><ng-rate-it ng-model="model.score" max="5" step="1" star-width="25" star-height="25" class="bigstar" read-only="false" resetable="false"></ng-rate-it>
</div>
```

Comment: can you show your full angular code? What is the console output?

Comment: you need this @ZombieChowder 
 $scope.allavispossible = response.data;

Comment: the console is showing no error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the array with each object having name and a score and change the ng-model as **`ng-model="avis.score"`**

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('testApp',['ngRateIt']);

app.controller('testCtrl',function($scope){
 
  $scope.allavispossible =[
  {
    "name": "presentation",
    "score": 5
  },
  {
    "name": "efficacite",
    "score": 3
  },
  {
    "name": "puissance",
    "score": 2
  }
];
});
```

```html
<link href="https://github.com/akempes/angular-rateit/blob/master/dist/ng-rateit.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jannunzi/educationPortal/master/public/js/ng-rateit.js"></script>
<body ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
<div ng-repeat="avis in allavispossible">
<span class="namecaracforvoteaddproduct">{{avis.name}}</span><ng-rate-it ng-model="avis.score" max="5" step="1" star-width="25" star-height="25" class="bigstar" read-only="false" resetable="false"></ng-rate-it>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, i know, to do this I need to change the data structure

Answer (score 0):

You tried to use Array as Object: ng-model="model.score". But model - is Array, you need to use it as Array, f.e. ng-model="model[0].score"